# How to read font color of each text in cell in apache poi 3.9

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[Text in 1 Cell]
ABC (Pink Color)
DEF (Black Color)
GHI (Red Color)

I have to check font color of text in cell like above.
(I'm sorry that I can't upload image)
Color of first row is pink. 
Color of next rows are black and red.

As you see, I can't use getCellStyle() method because the cell has 3 font attribute.

I typed source code like below.

`XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);`

`XSSFRichTextString value = cell.getRichStringCellValue();`

```
String[] info = value.getString().split("\n");
```

`for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {`

`int index = value.getString().indexOf(info);`
`System.out.println(value.getFontAtIndex(index).getColor());`

`}`

But, I didn't get correct result.
I want to know how I can get font information for each text.

Please inform me your great advice.
Thank a lots.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: It will work

```
   public static void differentColorInSingleCell(){
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
    Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    Font Font1 = wb.createFont();
    Font1.setColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
    Font Font2 = wb.createFont();
    Font2.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(Font1);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    RichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString("RED, BLUE");
    richString.applyFont(4, 9, Font2);
    cell.setCellValue(richString);
    //Write the file Now
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer. But I already try to do it you said. Poi provide example about making excel file and setting difference text color for each line. I want to read font information of each text line. When I make different text color in cell, I have to use applyFont method. When I want to read font information of each text, What must I do? Have a great day~ Thanks a lot~!