# Setting a part of the cell contents to Underline using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a program in which I have to set cell value in an Excel spreadsheet like

> "This is an **Underlined** text".

It can be anything Bold, Italic, or Underline.

I am using Apache POI 3.9

Comment: Can you post your attempt here specifying where are you facing the problem?

Comment: Actually i could not get code to do it so asking to code to do this, but now got it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public static void differentFontTypeInSameCell(){
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("TestSheet");
    Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    Font underlineFont = wb.createFont();
    underlineFont.setUnderline(HSSFFont.U_DOUBLE);
    Font boldFont = wb.createFont();
    boldFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    Font italicFont = wb.createFont();
    italicFont.setItalic(true);
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(underlineFont);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    RichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString("Underline, Bold, Italic");
    richString.applyFont(11, 15, boldFont);
    richString.applyFont(17, 23, italicFont);
    cell.setCellValue(richString);
}
```

Will look like [image]

You can change the font colors as well in the same way... refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675634/624003)

Comment: Thank you so much,this is the exact thing i am looking for :)

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to display this RichTextString on the JTextPane?

Comment: @Mustafa check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: thanks for the useful link but how to extract format from a richtextstring ? so that i can give it to the styled document.

Comment: While this came up on google first,  for Excel and more modern workbooks you may want this answer - similar but explicitly using XSS - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383469/4867303