# How to Underline only portions of text in single Excel cell using POI Library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In the single EXCEL cell, I have the following text:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Using poi library, is it possible to make only certain text (fox) underlined:

> The quick brown **fox** jumps over the lazy dog.

Thank you!

Comment: That is not exactly for Excel, but should be the same principle https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#Text ?

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932537/setting-a-part-of-the-cell-contents-to-underline-using-apache-poi