# Setting Some part of cell content to bold/italic using apache-poi 4.0.1 library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to set the content of cell value with a combination of bold and italic. 
like "This is ***Sample*** *content*."

However, this is not working using XSSFRichTextString.

I am using apache poi library version 4.0.1. I have tried making my content bold and italic combination using XSSFRichTextString. I have appended the string using by passing two arguments in method cell1Value.append("sample ", fontBold);i.e. String and Font.

```
    XSSFRichTextString cell1Value= new XSSFRichTextString("This is ");
    XSSFFont fontBold= wb.createFont();
    fontBold.setBold(true); //set bold
    fontBold.setUnderline(HSSFFont.U_SINGLE);


    XSSFFont fontItalic= wb.createFont();
    fontItalic.setItalic(true); //set italic

    cell1Value.append("sample ",fontBold);
    cell1Value.append("content", fontItalic);

    System.err.println(cell1Value.getCTRst());

    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
    cell1.setCellValue(cell1Value);
```

I am expecting "sample" to be bold and "content" to be italic. However, the underline is working fine and my "sample" word is underlined properly. Please suggest what I am missing?

Comment: _Some (rather silly) checks:_ Did you enlarge the view (zoom in), as maybe in the shown font size boldness might not be shown. Also the font might not be available in bold.

Comment: @JoopEggen
Yes, I checked the sheet by zooming it as well. when I apply the font style(only bold) using cell style method to a particular cell then It shows the content bold as well. 

cellStyle.setFont(setFontStyle(wb));

private XSSFFont setFontStyle(XSSFWorkbook wb) {
  XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
  font.setBold(true);
  return font;
 }  
Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
cell1.setCellValue("Some value"); 
cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);; 
But I need combination of both i.e bold and italic content in the cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TextBoldItalic {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    XSSFFont fontBold = wb.createFont();
    fontBold.setBold(true);
    XSSFFont fontItalic = wb.createFont();
    fontItalic.setItalic(true);
    XSSFFont fontBoldItalic = wb.createFont();
    fontBoldItalic.setBold(true);
    fontBoldItalic.setItalic(true);

    XSSFRichTextString cellValue = new XSSFRichTextString();
    cellValue.append("This is ", fontBold);
    cellValue.append("sample ", fontItalic);
    cellValue.append("content", fontBoldItalic);
    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);

    OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("TextBoldItalic.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    wb.close();
  }
}
```

This code works for me and gives me [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiVsb.png) in LibreOffice. OpenOffice is fine, too. No MS Excel here for a test, sorry. Of course tools like this [Online-Excel-Viewer](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/excelviewer) will not do it right. So, please try my code and make a report.

Comment: Thanks, It works with Libra office, but not with WPS spreadsheet. There might be some issue with WPS spreadsheet to pick both styles. Again thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the code looks plausible, just doing the complete run:

The following I have tested with

- org.apache.poi / poi / 3.16
- org.apache.poi / poi-ooxml / 3.16

It worked.

```
try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("With Rich Text");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    XSSFFont fontPlain = wb.createFont();

    XSSFFont fontBoldItalic = wb.createFont();
    fontBoldItalic.setBoldItalic(true);
    fontBoldItalic.setItalic(true);

    XSSFFont fontItalic = wb.createFont();
    fontItalic.setItalic(true);

    XSSFRichTextString cell1Value= new XSSFRichTextString("This is ");
    cell1Value.applyFont(fontPlain);
    cell1Value.append("sample ", fontBoldItalic);
    cell1Value.append("content", fontItalic);

    cell.setCellValue(cell1Value);
    wb.write(new FileOutputStream(xlsxFile));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My guess is a variable mix-up or something trivial. Maybe the font.

Comment: What `apache poi`version provides method `XSSFFont.setBoldItalic`?

Comment: @Joop Egeen, It didn't work. The cell content is not getting bold and italic. :(

Comment: I have tested and now added the entire code. It probably has nothing to do with the library. Maybe special font handling in your code?

Comment: @JoopEggen The problem was with WPS spreadsheet. I have checked the same code is working with Libra office now, but now with WPS spreadsheet. Thanks for your kind help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem using `WPS Spreadsheets` is that they claim to be most compatible to `Excel` but sometimes they totally fail. This time they misinterpret all Boolean font settings (bold, italic, strike) if they explicitly are set true.

`Office Open XML` provides Boolean elements having `val` attribute. Example: `<b val="true"/>` or `<b val="false"/>` or also  `<b val="1"/>` or `<b val="0"/>`. But for set bold font having `<b/>` would be enough. And for not set bold font simply not having the `b` element at all would be enough.

`Apache poi` always sets  `<b val="true"/>` for bold and  `<b val="false"/>`  for not bold. But `WPS Spreadsheets` now seems to misinterpret `<b val="true"/>`. It expects `<b/>` only.

The following code is the most compatible code for creating rich text strings for `Excel`. It supports  `Office Open XML (*.xlsx)` as well as `BIFF (*.xls)` and it corrects the `<Boolean val="true"/>` to  `<Boolean/>` only.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBooleanProperty;

class CreateExcelRichText {

 static RichTextString createRichTextString(Workbook workbook, String[] textParts, Font[] fonts) {
  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(String.join("", textParts));
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  for (int tp = 0; tp < textParts.length; tp ++) {
   Font font = null;
   if (tp < fonts.length) font = fonts[tp];
   end += textParts[tp].length();
   if (font != null) richTextString.applyFont(start, end, font);
   start += textParts[tp].length();
  }
  if (richTextString instanceof XSSFRichTextString) {
   //unset val="true" for boolean objects
   XSSFRichTextString xSSFRichTextString = (XSSFRichTextString)richTextString;
   String[] boolenanObjectsToUnset = new String[]{"b", "i", "strike"};
   for (String boolenanObjectToUnset : boolenanObjectsToUnset) {
    XmlObject[] xmlObjects = xSSFRichTextString.getCTRst().selectPath(
    "declare namespace main='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main' " +
    ".//main:" + boolenanObjectToUnset);
    for (XmlObject xmlObject : xmlObjects) {
     CTBooleanProperty booleanProperty = (CTBooleanProperty)xmlObject;
     if (booleanProperty.getVal()) booleanProperty.unsetVal();
    }
   }   
  }
  return richTextString;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 

  Font font = workbook.createFont();

  Font fontBoldItalic = workbook.createFont();
  fontBoldItalic.setBold(true);
  fontBoldItalic.setItalic(true);

  Font fontItalic = workbook.createFont();
  fontItalic.setItalic(true);

  Font fontStrikeout = workbook.createFont();
  fontStrikeout.setStrikeout(true);

  String[] textParts = new String[]{"This is ", "Sample ", "content. ", "This is crossed out."};
  Font[] fonts = new Font[]{font, fontBoldItalic, fontItalic, fontStrikeout};

  RichTextString richTextString = createRichTextString(workbook, textParts, fonts);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(richTextString);

  String fileName = (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook)?"Excel.xlsx":"Excel.xls";
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```